# Load data from API onclick

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I'm trying to make simple app. I want to show quotes on screen and I'm using API to get them. I'm using fetch to get API data.

Now everything works fine when window loads but I wanted to make button to get new quote each time someone clicks on that button and I can't get it to work.

This is my original code:

```
fetch('https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&callback=', {
  cache: "no-cache"
})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  
    data.filter(key => {
      
      let quote = document.getElementById('quote');
      let author = document.getElementById('author');
      
      quote.innerHTML = key.content;
      author.innerHTML = key.title;
      
    });

  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    // If there is any error you will catch them here
    console.log(error);
  });
```

To make quotes load on click I have tried following:

```
const newQuote = document.getElementById('newQuote')
 newQuote.addEventListener('click', _ => {
   fetch('https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&callback=', {
    mode: 'no-cors'
   })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      data.filter(key => {
          let quote = document.getElementById('quote')
          quote.innerHTML = key.content
      })
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err))
 })
```

So can I make it work with click event? Here is JSBin so you can better understand my problem:

https://jsbin.com/qidudat/edit?html,js,output

Comment: perhaps write your callback without the fat arrow, you may be losing the scope of `this`

Comment: @HolyMoly Tried it didn't work.

Comment: okay, so lets debug...when you console.log the API response, do you see the quotes? Have you verified that your HTML element is being correctly captured by the `document.getElementById('newQuote')`? why do you have the leading `//` prior to the API's url, rather than `http://` or something? have you console.log'd `data`?

Comment: are you getting any errors in console?

Comment: @HolyMoly Yeah you can check JSBin again and paste the first snippet of code into JS you will see data load. When I console.log api response I get json with data you can also see that if you use my first snippet. I've "//" used because I've thought CORS could be the problem.

Comment: sadly, i do not have an account with JSBin and it seems I would need to set one up to view your snippet.

Comment: @HolyMoly You don't need to have account. Just open my jsbin and change the code. Click console tab to open it. And use "run with js" button located in JS tab.

Comment: if you open the console tab in JSBin, and click the button you will see an error `[object Error] { ... }`I am not familiar with how to work with JSBin, but it looks like perhaps something is not being parsed correctly perhaps?

Comment: @HolyMoly Yeah I can see that it was fine with original code, but I don't know what is happening by my logic it should work.

Comment: when i console logged the scope of `this` with the fat arrow, it returned that it was pointing to the `window`. you want it to be pointing to your button. that is one issue, I am trying to find the other

Comment: your click event is indeed working on the button, your response body is `null`, which i do not know why - when i drop the API query directly in a new browser window it does return a response of a quote, as a single object. `data` comes in undefined. The `response.status` is returning a `0` you may need to check the API's docs. I see no reason why this isn't working, but it is failing at the first `.then`.

Comment: I read their a few times https://quotesondesign.com/api-v4-0/ but there I found nothing of any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've changed my approach to the problem. One of the issues was that I used `no-cors` mode.

Here is the solution for anyone interested:

```
function getQuote() {
  fetch("https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&callback=" + Math.random())
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(function(data) {
      console.log(data);

      data.filter(key => {

        let quote = document.querySelector(".quote");
        let author = document.querySelector(".author");
        let cleanQuote = key.content.replace(/<\/?p[^>]*>/g, ''); // This way we remove <p> tag from quote (api has quotes with p tags)

        let share = 'https://twitter.com/home?status=' + cleanQuote + ' Author: ' + key.title;
        console.log(share)

        quote.innerHTML = key.content;
        author.innerHTML = key.title;
        
        document.getElementById('twitterShare').href=share;
      });

    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      // If there is any error you will catch them here
      console.log(error);
    });
}

const newQuote = document.getElementById('newQuote')
newQuote.addEventListener('click', getQuote); // new quote on button click
window.onload = getQuote; // new quote on page load
```

Comment: For people, who will be testing the function by copying and pasting the code above: API of https://quotesondesign.com has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off caching when you use the fetch API call in your new code as well.... I think that should do it.

Comment: https://jsbin.com/pihokojiqi/edit?html,js,console,output

I used jQuery's $.ajax call to make the call, and it works. It seems like the API doesn't like fetch.....  I have attached the jsbin which console.logs a new quote each time you click the button. Good luck.

I am not sure why fetch didn't work....

Comment: I really wanted to solve this not using JQ and I finally did it. Thanks for your help thou